# Cookies set by a plugin in wordpress for tracking

Tags: plugins, cookies

We have our companies website on a wordpress-multisite-installation with some plugins:

- All-in-One WP Migration
- All-in-One WP Migration Multisite Extension
- Better Search Replace
- HTTP2 push content
- Polylang
- Security Headers
- Themify Updater
- WP-Optimize - Clean, Compress, Cache

One of this plugins seem to set the following cookies, mainly used for tracking and marketing. These cookies are only get set at some point when logged into wordpress.
https://cookiedatabase.org/service/rudderstack/

Of course we want to get rid of them. Though I cant figure out which plugin seems to cause the cookies. So far I tried the following:

- searching all files on the server for the cookie-name and "rudder" with the result of them appearing in the backup-files of  *All-in-One WP Migration* and *All-in-One WP Migration Multisite Extension*
- clicking through wordpress to find the place where they are set (included Firefox-Extensions uBlock and Ghostery) but it is not consistent and I am not sure if *All-in-One*-Plugins are truly the culprit
- this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946617/determining-origin-of-cookie-which-javascript-or-tracking-pixel without specific results.

Deactivating every plugin one by one could lead to the culprit but since the setting of these cookies seems to be not consistent, I am not sure.

Does somebody know where these cookies originate from?
What would you do to get rid of the cookies?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The database contained tables of tested plugins containing that cookies. Removing the old tables removes the cookies from the browser.